TYPO3 RTE - allowedClasses is TSconfig have no effect
I'm using TYPO v12.4. On a specific page of my website when I edit the "Page TSconfig" field with just one line:
RTE.default.proc.allowedClasses := addToList(custom, rowmax25, btn, btn-sm)

But this doesn't have any effect: when I add a class (ex: <p class="custom">) and I save, the class attribute is always removed from the paragraph. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.
My config seems to be active on the page:

Am I missing something here?  I read the documentation but I can't find anything that can help me further.

It's recommended to use the YAML configuration to configure the RTE.
https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor/main/en-us/Configuration/Reference.html#page-tsconfig
Best way is to copy following file to your sitepackage:
Copy:
vendor/typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Default.yaml
To:
EXT:your_sitepackage/Configuration/RTE/Default.yaml
And then add the config in:
EXT:your_sitepackage/ext_localconf.php
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['RTE']['Presets']['default'] = 'EXT:your_sitepackage/Configuration/RTE/Default.yaml';

In the Default.yaml file you have the following section:
editor:
  config:
    contentsCss: 'EXT:your_sitpackage/Resources/Public/Css/rte.css'

    style:
      definitions:
        - { name: "Custom", element: "p", classes: [ 'custom' ] }
        - { name: "Rowmax25", element: "small", classes: [ 'rowmax25' ] }
        - { name: "Btn", element: "span", classes: [ 'btn' ] }

There you can add your custom style classes. And also some css to style the text in the RTE.
For more information read:
https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor/main/en-us/Configuration/QuickStart.html#configuration-quickstart
EDIT 1:
Let's assume you want to have the possibilty to add a class to a table, like you described in your first comment. Then you just need to add following to the style definitions:
editor:
  config:
    style:
      definitions:
        - { element: 'table', classes: ['my-custom-class'] }
        

Now you can add class="my-custom-class" to a table-tag. When not adding a name to the definition, it will not show up in the style dropdown.
EDIT 2:
The EXT:fluid_styled_content comes with an HTML parser, that renders the classes for tables.
EXT:fluid_styled_content/Configuration/TypoScript/Helper/ParseFunc.typoscript
So in order to get your custom class rendered in the table-tag, you must add following to your TypoScript setup:
lib.parseFunc_RTE.externalBlocks.table.stdWrap.HTMLparser.tags.table.fixAttrib.class.list = contenttable, my-custom-class

Now the class should be rendered as set in the RTE.

Hi, I don't want to add a custom style definition but I want to allow a contributor to add a specific CSS class on a  if he wants to. I already read the doc but what you explained is useful for adding a new style into the style dropdown, not allowing a CSS class to not being stripped when saving a content?

Updated my answer

Hello @Mogens, that works! Perfect. However, it saves the class but when I watch the result in front-end the class has been replaced by another one (ex: <table class="contenttable">) What is this processing ?

That's because of the HTML parser of EXT:fluid_styled_content. Updated my answer.

Thank you for your second update. Unfortunately it doesn't work

Sorry. Had a typo in the TypoScript. Missed the stdWrap. Now it should work. ;-)

Still doesn't work. I cleared all the caches, reload the back-end, the only class in front-end is "contenttable". I checked the Page TSconfig and the lib.parseFunc_RTE [...] is set, but has no effects on front-end. By the way I appreciate the help!

The Typoscript is not set in Page TsConfig. You need to set it in the TypoScript Setup. EXT:your_sitepackage/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.typoscript or if you dont have custom TypoScript you could also set it the Page Template TypoScript setup.

It works now! Again, thank you very much for your help.
